# Sharing a React Context between children without retriggering parents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rendering components from a list. Each of these components has a deeply nested button, which has access to the unique `id` of the component it's in. I'm trying to have that button access the state of all other instances of that button, in the sibling components of the component that contains that button. I can do this with a Context at the top level, above the list of components, but I don't want the entire list of components to be re-rendered when the buttons change.

In the simplified code below, the idea is to add a button's `id` to the shared state, so that all buttons can know which of the buttons in the sibling components have been clicked. However this of course doesn't work, because each button is a child of a different instance of the `ButtonContextProvider` component, each of which has its own state.

In the parent component where the button is nested, I have this:

```js
<ButtonContextProvider>
    <Button id={someId} />
</ButtonContextProvider>
```

And the Context is defined like this:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { ToggleButton } from './Toggles'

export const ButtonContext = createContext()

export const ButtonContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState([])

  const handleButton = (id) => {
    if (!buttonState.includes(id)) {
      setButtonState([...buttonState, id])
    } else {
      setButtonState(buttonState.filter((i) => i !== id))
    }
  }

  return (
    <ButtonContext.Provider value={{buttonState, handleButton}}>
      {children}
    </ButtonContext.Provider>
  )
}


export const Button = ({ id }) => {
  const buttonContext = useContext(ButtonContext)

  const handleClick = () => {
    buttonContext.handleButton(id)
  }

  console.log(buttonContext.buttonState)
  return (
    <>
      <ToggleButton onClick={handleClick}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

How can I share a global state at a granular level as I'd like to, without resorting to moving the context provider to the top of the hierarchy and pre-rendering the entire component on state change?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I thought was you could just a button's state up to their common list item parent component. But since they are deeply nested, this could quickly become tedious. So stick with context, but break the dependency between the ButtonContext and the Button component.
Within the components rendered from a list, have each component create import and create it's own instance of ButtonContext, and pass that value down to it's descendants. It could also pass a function it's descendant's use to update that state, which will be held by the list item component.

Comment: When you say "pass that value", that value has to be stored in a state somewhere. And if I store it in the parent component, all children up to and including the buttons are re-rendered when the value is changed, which is not want I want. The top component added from each list item doesn't need the value at all. That's why I thought of using a container such as  `ButtonContextProvider` holding the logic for the state changes. But I don't how to have all `Buttons` share a single and same instance of the Provider's state.

Comment: By "pass that value" I mean using context. The parent component may not need it, but all its Button children need to know what their siblings are doing. That's the best place to store it, a common parent. React doc call this "lifting state up", and you are using the context API to do this. Your ButtonContextProvider look's like a singleton pattern, where just one "global" state for all Button instances is being held. If I understand you correctly, this is not what you want.

Comment: As I wrote in my comment above, if I store the state in the top of the component hierarchy, all children up to and including the buttons are re-rendered when the value is changed, which is not want I want. I would like only the buttons to be re-rendered when the state changes, if that's possible, and have a separate component hold the state in a Context. Apologies if this isn't clear from what I wrote above.

Comment: From "I store the state in the top of the component hierarchy", this means at the top of your applications component hierarchy? That's how I understood it.

What I'm suggesting is you store a separate context for each one of the "I'm rendering components from a list. Each of these components has a deeply nested button" components.

Comment: Have a look at the pattern used here, it sounds very similar to what you have discribed.

https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#context-an-alternative-to-passing-props